# default schema synonym

Tags: sql-server

I have a database `FooDb` with a schema `BarSchema` that contains a table `Tbl` (i.e. `FooDb.BarSchema.Tbl`)

I am also logged in as a user with `BarSchema` as default.

This query works fine

```
SELECT * FROM FooDb..Tbl
```

I also have a synonym for this table in another db

```
CREATE SYNONYM TblSynonym FOR FooDb..Tbl
```

But now I get an error **"Invalid object name 'FooDb..Tbl'"** when executing

```
SELECT * FROM TblSynonym
```

If i change the synonym to

```
CREATE SYNONYM TblSynonym FOR FooDb.BarSchema.Tbl
```

it works fine.

Why doesn't the default schema work in synonyms?

(The background is that I'm consoldating data from several databases which all got same table names but different schema names. It would be a lot easier if I could set the default schema for each database on the user and then ignore it everywhere in the script)

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) suggests the `db..tbl` syntax should work:

> schema_name_2    Is the name of the
>   schema of the base object. If
>   schema_name is not specified the
>   default schema of the current user is
>   used.

This works for me in SQL Server 2008:

```
create synonym TestSynonym for TestDB..TestTable
```

One cause might be that the default schema is associated with the user, not the database.  Check if your user has an unexpected default schema?  In my SSMS, that setting is located under Database -> Security -> Users -> Properties.

Comment: I have verified that the default schema is correct under both Database->Security->Users and Connection->Security->Logins->User.
(The error happens when using the synonym, not when creating it)